# What is the distribution of $\frac{s^2}{10x̅^2}$

Tags: statistics

For $X_1, ...., X_{10}$, a random sample of size 10 with a normal population with mean 0 and variance $σ^2$ . Let x̅ be the sample mean and $s^2$ be the sample variance. How would one find the distribution of:

$\frac{s^2}{10x̅^2}$

I'm really struggling to figure this one out. (The answer is $F_{9,1}$)

Comment: What is $F_{9,1}$?

Comment: F distribution with degrees of freedom 9 and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem#Sample_mean_and_sample_variance) (see also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662/why-is-the-sampling-distribution-of-variance-a-chi-squared-distribution)) implies that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} (X_i - \bar{x})^2/ \sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_9$$
and $$10 \bar{x}^2 / \sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_1$$
and that the two are independent.

Thus $$\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10} (X_i - \bar{x})^2/ \sigma^2\right) / 9}{(10\bar{x}^2 / \sigma^2) / 1} = \frac{s^2}{10 \bar{x}^2}$$
follows the $F_{9,1}$ distribution.